# New to MIPS and having issues with getting it to read the input

Tags: java, list, mips, user-input

I have been given the Java code and instructed to use it to make a MIPS program that does the same thing. When I go to run it, all I get is the prompt. Supposed to look through the list and find if the number is there.

```
 #  // ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE PROGRAM
#
#   import java.io.*;
#   
#   public class CIS2233StarterCode2Java {
#   
#   public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
#   
#   BufferedReader kbd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
#   int [] list = {5,7,4,6,3,8,2,9,0,20,21,29,22,28,23,27,24,26,25,30,31,39,32,38,33,37,34,36,35,10,11,19,12,18,13,17,14,16,15,1};
#   String prompt1 = "\nPlease enter an array element: ";
#   String prompt2 = "\nPlease enter a search target: ";
#   String space = " ";
#   String nfound = "\nThe target was not found.";
#   String found = "\nThe target was fount at array location ";
#   int t0 = 0;
#   int t1 = 0;
#   int t2 = 39;
#   int t3 = 39;
#   int t4;
#   int t5;
#   int t6;
#   int a0;
#   int v0;
#   // address calculation register t7
#   // base address of array register t8
#   // address calculation register t9
#   do {
#       System.out.print (prompt1);
#       v0 = Integer.parseInt(kbd.readLine());
#       list [t0] = v0;
#       t0 ++;
#   } while (t0 <= t2);
#   t0 = 0;
#   do {
#       t1 = 0;
#       do {
#           t4 = list [t1];
#           t5 = list [t1 + 1];
#           if (t4 > t5) {
#               list [t1 + 1] = t4;
#               list [t1] = t5;
#           }
#           t1 ++;
#       } while (t1 < t3);
#       t3 --;
#       t0 ++;
#   } while (t0 < t2);
#   t0 = 0;
#   do {
#       a0 = list [t0];
#       System.out.print (a0);
#       System.out.print (space);
#       t0 ++;
#   } while (t0 <= t2);
```

The MIPS code is below:

```
.data
    list:       .word 5
            .word 7
            .word 4
            .word 6
            .word 3
            .word 8
            .word 2
            .word 9
            .word 0
            .word 30
            .word 31
            .word 39
            .word 32
            .word 38
            .word 33
            .word 37
            .word 34
            .word 36
            .word 35
            .word 20
            .word 21
            .word 29
            .word 22
            .word 28
            .word 23
            .word 27
            .word 24
            .word 26
            .word 25
            .word 10
            .word 11
            .word 19
            .word 12
            .word 18
            .word 13
            .word 17
            .word 14
            .word 16
            .word 15
            .word 1         # last array element
            .word -1            # not part of array
    prompt1:    .asciiz "\nPlease enter an array element: "
    prompt2:    .asciiz "\nPlease enter a search target: "
    space:  .asciiz " "
    nfound: .asciiz "\nThe target was not found."
    found:  .asciiz "\nThe target was found at array location "

            .text
            .globl main
    main:       add $t0, $zero, $zero   # [main]
            add $t1, $zero, $zero   #
            addi $t2, $zero, 39 #
            addi $t3, $zero, 39 #
            add $t4, $zero, $zero   #
            add $t5, $zero, $zero   #
            add $t6, $zero, $zero   #
    #       add $t7, $zero, $zero   #
            la $t8, list

    read:       addi $v0, $zero, 4  # [read]
            la $a0, prompt1     #
            syscall
            addi $v0, $zero, 5  #
            syscall
            sll $t7, $t0, 2     #
            add $t9, $t8, $t7
            sw $v0, 0($t9)
            addi $t0, $t0, 1        #
            ble $t0, $t2, read  #
            add $t0, $zero, $zero   #
    # add the code that is missing from right here

search:     add $t4, $t1, $t1
        addi $t5, $t1, 1
        sgt $t1, $t4, $t5
        addi $t4, $t1, 1        
        add $t5, $t1, $t1
        add $t1, $t1, 1
        blt $t3, $t1, search
        sub $t3, $t3, 1
        add $t0, $t0, 1
        blt $t2, $t0, search

    print:      addi $v0, $zero, 1  # [print]
            sll $t7, $t0, 2     #
            add $t9, $t8, $t7
            lw $a0, 0($t9)
            syscall
            addi $v0, $zero, 4  #
            la $a0, space       #
            syscall
            addi $t0, $t0, 1        #
            ble $t0, $t2, print #

    end:        addi $v0, $zero, 10 # [end]
            syscall
```

Edit 4:40 9/25/2015: I ran it through the MIPS simulator (MARS) and it won't run unless i go through the code step by step. Seems to just keep asking the user for the prompt.

Edit 2:08 9/27/2015: Keeps doing the same thing even after I rewrote my search section. Can I get some help here?

```
        .data
list:       .word 5
        .word 7
        .word 4
        .word 6
        .word 3
        .word 8
        .word 2
        .word 9
        .word 0
        .word 30
        .word 31
        .word 39
        .word 32
        .word 38
        .word 33
        .word 37
        .word 34
        .word 36
        .word 35
        .word 20
        .word 21
        .word 29
        .word 22
        .word 28
        .word 23
        .word 27
        .word 24
        .word 26
        .word 25
        .word 10
        .word 11
        .word 19
        .word 12
        .word 18
        .word 13
        .word 17
        .word 14
        .word 16
        .word 15
        .word 1         # last array element
        .word -1            # not part of array
prompt1:    .asciiz "\nPlease enter an array element: "
prompt2:    .asciiz "\nPlease enter a search target: "
space:  .asciiz " "
nfound: .asciiz "\nThe target was not found."
found:  .asciiz "\nThe target was found at array location "

        .text
        .globl main
main:       add $t0, $zero, $zero   # [main]
        add $t1, $zero, $zero   #
        addi $t2, $zero, 39 #
        addi $t3, $zero, 39 #
        add $t4, $zero, $zero   #
        add $t5, $zero, $zero   #
        add $t6, $zero, $zero   #
#       add $t7, $zero, $zero   #
        la $t8, list

read:       addi $v0, $zero, 4  # [read]
        la $a0, prompt1     #
        syscall
        addi $v0, $zero, 5  #
        syscall
        sll $t7, $t0, 2     #
        add $t9, $t8, $t7
        sw $v0, 0($t9)
        addi $t0, $t0, 1        #
        ble $t0, $t2, read  #

# add the code that is missing from right here
        add $t0, $zero, $zero   #

search:     add $t1, $zero, $zero

search2:    lw $t4, 0($t9)
        lw $t5, 1($t9)
        sgt $t7, $t4, $t5
        sw $t4, 0($t9)
        sw $t5, 1($t9)
        blt $t1, $t3, search2
        sub $t3, $t3, 1
        add $t0, $t0, 1
        blt $t0, $t2, search

print:      addi $v0, $zero, 1  # [print]
        sll $t7, $t0, 2     #
        add $t9, $t8, $t7
        lw $a0, 0($t9)
        syscall
        addi $v0, $zero, 4  #
        la $a0, space       #
        syscall
        addi $t0, $t0, 1        #
        ble $t0, $t2, print #

end:        addi $v0, $zero, 10 # [end]
        syscall
```

Comment: Step through the code in a MIPS simulator like SPIM or MARS.

Comment: did that and it keeps going through the same lines of code over and over again

Comment: What lines of code is it repeating? Perhaps you have an unmet loop exit condition.

Comment: it changes between the search section and the print section. i updated the code but still isn't quite working right.

Comment: seems to do it in the java code too

Comment: All i keep getting in the MARS when I run the code is the user prompt over and over again and never moves on.

Comment: I should say it does the same in the java code, really pulling my hair out here, need help

Comment: the longer i wait the more hair i seem to lose and soon i will be bald. HELP!